# retain angular variables after page refresh

Tags: angularjs, page-refresh

I'm trying to figure out a way to keep my `angular` variables with page refresh / across controllers. My workflow is,

- user logs in via facebook and gets an access token
- users access token will be used with every request

I tried two ways,

1 - Assigning the token to a `rootScope`
    Not working

2 - By using a `factory`

```
#app.js
'use strict';

angular.module('recipeapp', [])
 .run(['$rootScope', '$injector', 'Authenticate', function($rootScope,$injector, Authenticate){
            $injector.get("$http").defaults.transformRequest = function(data, headersGetter) {
                $injector.get('$http').defaults.headers.common['auth-token'] = Authenticate.getToken();
             }
        }]);

#factory
'use strict';
angular.module('recipeapp')
  .factory('Authenticate', function(){
    var factory = {};
    var accessToken = "";

    factory.setToken = function(token) {
       accessToken = token;
    }
    factory.getToken = function() {
       return accessToken;
    }

    return factory;

  })

#facebook controller
I set the the token with every successful login
Authenticate.setToken(data.app_token);
```

But the problem is, If I refresh the page, `Authenticate.getToken()` becomes blank. I'm pretty new to `angular` and cannot figure out a way to retain my data after a page refresh

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `localStorage`. It is really easy to use.

```
var token = "xxx";
localStorage.setItem("token", token);
localStorage.getItem("token"); //returns "xxx"
```

Comment: Not working for me, got this error :- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'title' of undefined

Answer (score 12):

When you refresh a page all your JavaScript context is lost (including all data saved in variables).

One way to maintaing information from one session to another is to use the browser's localStorage. In your case, you probably want to check [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage).

Answer (score 5):

I did the same using $window.localStorage.

It is kind of similar to accepted answer.

```
var token = "xxx";
$window.localStorage.setItem("token",token);
$window.localStorage.getItem("token"); //returns "xxx"
$window.localStorage.removeItem("token"); //deletes token
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use cookies

To put simple variable

```
$cookies.put('user', 'abc');
```

To save object

```
$cookies.putObject('objSocket', anyObject);
```

and to get back data from cookies use

```
$cookies.getObject('objSocket');
```

and

```
$cookies.get('user');
```

To use above code cookies.js cdnjs is :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
```

Now inject `$cookies` into your controller and `ngCookies` into your **app.js**

for more detail
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies

Comment: Is Local Storage a safe way to do this? There Must be a way to store the values permanently like declaring the const identifier. As my case is the same. Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
use `localStorage.setItem("key",value);` to set the value.
use `localStorage.getItem("key");`to get the value.
use `localStorage.clear();`to clear the value which is set
```

Comment: Is Local Storage a safe way to do this? There Must be a way to store the values permanently like declaring the const identifier. As my case is the same. Please help