# AngularJS data lost on refreshing the page

Tags: angularjs

Each time I refresh my page, the data in AngularJS variables is lost. How to retain them without using cookies? Can anyone help me with an approach? Its different from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26118851/retain-angular-variables-after-page-refresh) because I am interested in a solution that does not use cookies.

Comment: use localstorage? As variables are stored in memory, you have to save them in persistent storage.

Comment: Are you using routing in your app?

Comment: I am using `ngRoute` in my `angular.module`

Comment: localforage.js would help you for localstorage

Comment: I shall try picking up things from the post. Thanks. But its not really duplicate

Comment: why did u mark it duplicate.It helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For amounts of data less than 4k you can use $cookieStore.
If it is more than that you'll need to look into HTML5 localStorage

> For more details please go through this post you will find different
>   options of storage with comparison
>   http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/

Comment: is there not another way than using cookies? I wanna avoid it

Comment: You can use localStorage

Comment: Go through this links https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage

Comment: Thanks for the input. M trying.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you have only 2 options here:

1. Use localStorage. There're lots of handy localStorage angularJS modules to use.
2. If you don't want to store data on the client side, you could request your API for the data you need to store each time your angular app is getting loaded. This data seems to be static, as you are storing it on client side and reuse then, so you could configure API endpoint to throw this data really fast.

Comment: I used localStorage and its working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use `localStorage.setItem("key",value);` to set the value.

use `localStorage.getItem("key");`to get the value.

use `localStorage.clear();`to clear the value which is set