# Value is vanishing after refresh the controller using factory method o angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue. I am setting the value in route page using factory method to call those value in all controller using Angular.js but when I am refreshing any controller page the `undefined` value is coming. I am providing my code below.

route.js:

```
var app=angular.module('ikomplianzNABH',['ui.router','angular.chosen']);
app.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
      $rootScope.$state = $state;
    });
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    .state('/', { /*....This state defines All type of user login...*/
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'View/NABH.html',
        controller: 'NABHParentController'
    })
    .state('initiateaudit', { /*....This state defines All type of user login...*/
        url: '/initiateaudit',
        templateUrl: 'View/auditDetail.html',
        controller: 'auditdetailController'
    })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: true
    });
});
app.factory('getBothIdToAuditDetailPage',function($timeout, $window){
    var value ={};
    return{
        setClauseValue:function(cid){
            value.setClauseId=cid;
        },
        getClauseValue:function(){
            return value.setClauseId;
        }
    }
})
```

firstController.js:

```
var app=angular.module('ikomplianzNABH');
app.controller('firstController',function($scope,$http,$state,$window,getBothIdToAuditDetailPage){
    getBothIdToAuditDetailPage.setClauseValue(1234);
})
```

In this controller I am setting the value to controller.

secondController.js:

```
var app=angular.module('ikomplianzNABH');
app.controller('secondController',function($scope,$http,$state,$window,getBothIdToAuditDetailPage){
    console.log('both id'getBothIdToAuditDetailPage.getClauseValue());

})
```

Here I am fetching that value set in `firstController.js` . Here I can get the value or first time but while I am refreshing the `controller/page` I am getting the undefined value. Here I need that value while this conroller will execute.

Comment: _I am refreshing the controller/page_, How are you refreshing? `F5`/Route reload???

Comment: I am doing `F5` or rereshing using the browser icon.

Comment: Then data will lose as Angular Application will reinitialize, You can use [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: But I need to retain that value. Suppose someone set value already first time getting the value but while wrongly refresing the page the undefined value is coming.

Comment: Like I said try with sessionStorage i.e. to set use `sessionStorage.setItem('clauseId', 'cid');` and `return sessionStorage.getItem('clauseId')`

Comment: Ok, Will it be over write every call of that function ?

Answer (score 0):

For persisting anything after page reload ,the best option is to use local storage for it and on logout you can clear the local storage.

On page reload check if the value is present in local storage or else fetch from network request.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26118991/4861453